# Switch Between Main Layout Rtl and Main Layout Ltr in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I look for to switch between the main layout RTL and main layout LTR, when the user selects the English language will set in layout LTR and when the user selects Arabic will set to layout RTL.

I did that but it's don't work below :

```
@if (Session::get('locale') ==='ar')
   @extends('layouts.main-rtl')
@elseif(Session::get('locale') ==='en')
   @extends('layouts.main')
@endif
```

in my debug laravel I see this see in the screenshot below :
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post the code where you are setting the session variables

Answer (score 4):

Use [ternary calls](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead to select what file you want to use. This will prevent `@extends` to be called twice.

```
@extends(Session::get('locale') === 'ar' ? 'layouts.main-rtl' : 'layouts.main')
```